# get google sheet cell value based on value of other cell

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, indexing, vlookup, index-match

[image]

Is it possible in google sheets to write a formula that calculates the cell to fetch based on the value of another.

In this case i would want cell B2 to print the value of e2 so be something like:

```
='a2'2
```

Is this possible in google sheets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=HLOOKUP(A2; E1:F2; 2; 0)
```

Comment: This works, thank you! Is it possible to make the index value dynamic to the row it is on? It is currently set to 2, but if i drag the row down the index value remains the same. `=HLOOKUP(A5, $E$1:F5, 5, 0)` for example when dragging the cell down the row 5, i had to manually update the index to 5.

Comment: @John sure. instead of `2` use `ROW(A2)`

Comment: ah! so simple ha! nice thanks